# Display array elements with delay

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have an array`s=[John; Alex; Mark]`, I wanna to show the elements of this array one by one by 3 second delay.

```
for (var i=0; i<=3; i++)
  {
     setTimeout(function(){x.innerHTML=s[i]},3000)
  }
```

It seems very simple problem, but I can't figure out.

Comment: (at least) three errors in four lines of code...

Comment: Did you look at the console in the browser for error messages?

Comment: ok, make that _five_ errors...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript SetTimeout and Loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791158/javascript-settimeout-and-loops)

Comment: Note that I voted as duplicate for the 2 main errors but Alnitak found other problems (which should have been found by OP with a little care). This question shouldn't be deleted thus in my opinion.

Comment: do you want to repeat the display/stop after displaying it once

Comment: I am new in the js, and I typed in the another pc, so the files that I work wasn't with me, just typed hoping, somebody can understand. Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. your loop runs four times, not three
2. `setTimeout` starts with a lower case `s`
3. your delay should be 3000 for 3 seconds, not 2000
4. your delay should be `3000 * i`, not `3000` or they'll all fire at once
5. you can't use loop variables inside an asynchronous callback without special precautions - the callbacks will all see the last value assigned to `i`, not the values it had as you went through the loop.

This works, and completely avoids the loop variable issue:

```
var s = ['John', 'Mark', 'Alex'];
var i = 0;

(function loop() {
    x.innerHTML = s[i];
    if (++i < s.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 3000);  // call myself in 3 seconds time if required
    }
})();      // above function expression is called immediately to start it off
```

Note how it uses "pseudo-recursion" to trigger the next iteration 3000ms after the completion of the previous iteration.  This is preferable to having `n` outstanding timers all waiting at the same time.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/mHQVz/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/mHQVz/1/

I got to tinkering... albeit this is probably not the best solution it was fun.

```
var x = document.getElementById('x'),
    s = ['John', 'Mark', 'Alex'];

(function loop() {
    s.length && (x.innerHTML = s.shift(), setTimeout(loop, 3000));
})();
```

[Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15788574/829835)'s solution is alot better. However they both would work (his is just more readable and less hacky also does not destroy the array).

Answer (score 1):

this will also help:

```
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'mango', 'guava'];
let index = 0;
const primtMe = (value, i) => {
    if (i < fruits.length) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(i + ' value = ' + value)
            primtMe(fruits[i + 1], i + 1)
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

primtMe(fruits[index], index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work, since you set *four* timeouts of 2000 milliseconds (i.e. *2 seconds*) at a time. You'd better use closure that sets *three* timeouts (by number of elements in array) with *3000 milliseconds* of delay. It can be done with the following code (note that `setTimeout` is written from the small letter):

```
var s = ["John", "Alex", "Mark"];
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            x.innerHTML = s[i];
        }, 3000 * i);
    })(i);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6Ne6z/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var s=['John', 'Alex', 'Mark'];
var x = document.getElementById('x');

function display(i){
    if(i >= s.length){
        i = 0;
    }

    x.innerHTML = s[i];
    setTimeout(function(){
       display(i + 1)
    }, 2000)
}

display(0)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fk3sV/1/)

Comment: why are you restarting the loop over when it reaches the end of the list?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use closure, you will end up with i being undefined. This is because in each iteration you are overriding what i is. By the time it finishes, it will be undefined. Using a closure will preserve i.

On another note, it's kind of pointless to hard code in values (i.e. i<3) when you can just check for length. This way, if s ever changes, you for loop will still grab everything.

```
var s = ['john','mark','brian'];
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            x.innerHTML = s[i];
        }, 3000*(i+1));
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to show elements one by one after 3 seconds delay:

```
s=["John", "Alex", "Mark"];

var i = 0;
var id = setInterval(function(){                
            if(i > s.length) {                  
                clearInterval(id);                  
            }
            else{
                console.log(s[i++]);
            }
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this without pseudo-recursion

```js
var arr = [10,20,30,40]; // your array
var i = 0;
var interval = 2000 // 2 sec, you can add your time required
function callInterval() {
// set a variable for setInterval
 var time = setInterval(()=>{
  console.log('['+arr[i]+','+i+']');
  i++; 
  if(i==arr.length){
   this.clearInterval(time);// clear the interval after the index
  }
  }, interval);
}

callInterval();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using setInterval. Here is my solution:

```js
function delayPrint(arr, delay) {
    let index = -1;

    const interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (++index === arr.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }

        console.log(arr[index]);
    }, delay);
}

let s = ['John', 'Alex', 'Mark'];

delayPrint(s, 3000);

// output:
// John after 3s
// Alex after 3s
// Mark after 3s
```