# Strange javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

anybody can help me with the following Js syntax?
I don't understand the line starting with "( $.inArray( wzdId, this...."
I mean why does that line start with just a parentesis? 
What does it mean?

This is the complete code:

```
_activateStep: function( wzdId ) {
  if ( condition ) {
    var stepIndex = this._findNav( wzdId ).index(); 
    for( var i = 0; i < stepIndex; ++i) { 
      if( condition ) === -1 ) {
        return;
      }
    }
    ( $.inArray( wzdId, this._activatedSteps ) === -1 ) && this._activatedSteps.push( wzdId );
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The parenthesis (`(...)`) in this case are the *grouping operator*. You can use it to change the order of precedence or just make expressions more readable. For example: `6 * (4 + 3)` or `(5 * 2) + (4 * 8)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you have here is

```
A && B
```

It uses a common trick based on short-circuit [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) : B is executed only if A is true.

That's another way to write

```
if (A) B;
```

Some people like it because it's a little shorter. It's obviously much less readable too.

Comment: the braces can be around either of the statements. afaik. I often A && (B) myself.

Comment: I use the OR (`||`) operator to set defaults like `var a = yourPassVal || 0`, but you have to be careful for when a falsey value is allowed and your default isn't it.

Comment: and you can do so much fun stuff with it [example from another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15789302/829835)

Comment: Clear and quick!
Thanks to all of you for your help!