# Using settimeout to queue functions in a delayed manner?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Update: I edited the `setTimeout()` code to run the code inside a function, but now nothing runs at all. I also changed the function to accept `drawcount`, `i`, and `j`, making the call `appendcharacter(drawcount, i, j)`. It still does nothing at all (although originally it ran, all at the same time). For some reason `setTimeout` is not running the function properly after the timeout.

--Original Question--

I have the following code (note not all variables are listed, just what was relevant or was with this section of code). I would like to stagger the running of `appendcharacter(drawcount)` so that it will run in half-second intervals, yet this code runs everything at exactly the same time:

```
        var $span, $br;
        var $img = $('#image');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var drawcount = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < imgwidth; j++) {
                $("#image").append("<br>");

                for (var i = 0; i < imgheight; i++) {
                    var timeout = 500 * drawcount;
                    console.log(timeout);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        appendcharacter(drawcount, i, j);
                    },timeout);
                    drawcount++;
                }
            }


            function appendcharacter(drawcount, i, j) {
                $span = $("<span id='" + i + "_" + j + "' style='position:relative; display: inline; color: rgba(" + pixels[j][i].red + " , " + pixels[j][i].green + " , " + pixels[j][i].blue + ", 1);'></span>").appendTo($img);
                switch (drawcount % 18) {
                    case 0:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("/");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("-");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("/");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("-");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("/");
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("-");
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("(");
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("8");
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("8");
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append(")");
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("-");
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("\\");
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("-");
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("\\");
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("-");
                        break;
                    case 16:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("\\");
                        break;
                    case 17:
                        $("#" + i + "_" + j).append("  ");
                        break;
                }
            }


        });
```

Comment: `appendcharacter(drawcount)` calls the function immediately. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14791158/139010 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/q/3583724/139010

Comment: They're 500 milliseconds apart, hence `500 * drawcount`. I fixed the other error. Now it's not running at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking the function `appendcharacter` and passing the value returned by it as the callback to the `setTimeout` method.

You need to pass a function reference to the `setTimeout` which will get invoked, you also need to use a local closure function because of the reference to shared variable `drawcount` in the callback

```
        (function(drawcount, i, j){
            setTimeout(function () {
                appendcharacter(drawcount, i, j);
            }, timeout);
        })(drawcount, i, j)
```

You also need to pass i and j as aprams to `appendcharacter`

ex

```
function appendcharacter(drawcount, i, j) {
    ..
}
```

Comment: @MattBall yes just saw the closure problem

Comment: This, along with the edited code in the post above does not run anything.

Comment: @Jamil I've made a slight change using a anonymous callback function

Comment: This doesn't work either.. I changed `i` and `j` to be passed to the function i.e. `appendcharacter(drawcount, i, j)` and `function appendcharacter(drawcount, i, j){}`, but that didn't solve it either.