# Binding for loop iterator values to callback functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I set the values to the callback function, so that it's saved and ready to fire when the element is clicked?

```
for (i=0; i < ELEMENTS-1; i++) {
    array[i].click(function(){
        array[i].insertAfter(array[i+1]); 
        //other stuff
    });
}
```

`array[]` just contains a bunch of divs.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="one" class="tile">One</div>
        <div id="two" class="tile">Two</div>
        <div id="three" class="tile">Three</div>
        <div id="four" class="tile">Four</div>
    </div>
```

When a div is clicked, I want it to move down the list.

Comment: This is one of the most frequent questions here, see link.

Comment: @mshsayem I don't think you understand the problem

Comment: @dystroy - While it is one of the most commonly asked questions here -- if you've never run into it before you have no idea what to even LOOK for when trying to solve it.   You have to admit, it is pretty non-obvious first time you run into it.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Yes. No need for downvotes (or not too much). But now we should close it properly.

Comment: [Here's another similar QA with other explanations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791158/javascript-settimeout-and-loops).

Comment: @dystroy Both those answers implement a `setTimeout` function - why is this necessary?

Comment: @tgun926 no, but the closure trick also works in your case

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use:

```
$('.wrapper div').click(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).next());    
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cr9Tq/)**

Comment: This won't help OP learn how to solve this general class of problem

Comment: @dystroy Since you already post comments related to his problem, do I need to post it again in my answer?

Comment: note : I'm not the downvoter. If it works I don't see any good reason to downvote